# Ruby on rails views without mixing ruby and html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsf

I started learning Rails. What I don't like is that it uses JSP-like code, mixing html and ruby. I'm familiar with JSF 2.0 and like its approach. Is there something similar in Rails?

A good example to compare with could be found at http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/

```
<h:dataTable value="#{order.orderList}" var="o"
    styleClass="order-table"
    headerClass="order-table-header"
    rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row" >

    <h:column>
        <!-- column header -->
        <f:facet name="header">Order No</f:facet>
        <!-- row record -->
        #{o.orderNo}
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Product Name</f:facet>
        #{o.productName}
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Price</f:facet>
        #{o.price}
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Quantity</f:facet>
        #{o.qty}
    </h:column>

</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: But that is the way web frameworks are working. Do you have an example what you want to reach? In some way, you have to integrate your computation in the HTML template ... Done that right, with partials and the right division, the code is very readable. Could you explain what is the deficit in Rails compared for example to a [Hello World in JSF](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/)?

Comment: It's better to look at this example: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/  While in Rails I will write all this <td> and <tr> with loops. Or there is other option?

Comment: There really isn't a similar option, Rails really isn't about encapsulating view logic into tags. You can go a long way with judicious use of helpers and partials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the example and tried to come up with reasonable Rails code to compare to. After that, I would like to look at the differences:

First the HAML example

```
%table.order-table  
  %thead
    %tr
      - ["Order No", "Product Name", "Price", "Quantity"].each do |h|
        %th.order-table-header
          h 
  %tbody
    - order.orderList.each do |o|
      %tr
        [#orderNo, #productName, #price, #qty].each do |s|
          %td= o.send(s)
```

There are parts in it I don't like either, and I am missing the even / odd row thing. But the code is as clear as your example. If you take that one step further, and create partials for all the little bits, it won't get clearer in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

HAML is a great choice. http://haml-lang.com/tutorial.html That might not be what you're looking for exactly, but I highly recommend it if you're not happy with ERB.